# Concatenate XML fields in one single record

Tags: c#, xml, concatenation, record

I am new to working with XML in C#. I have a requirement to concatenate multiple fields in one single record.
For example I have an XML with multiple Records:

**Input**

```
 <Students>---------------------->1st Record
      <Validate>True</Validate>
      <StudentName>Joe</StudentName>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <BookName>C#</BookName>
 </Students>
 <Students>----------------------->2nd Record
      <StudentName>Van</StudentName>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <BookName>Java</BookName>
 </Students>
```

The field `<validate>` will occur only once and the expected Output is that the 2nd Record under students i.e StudentName, ID, BookName should come under the 1st Record `<Students>` tag

**OutPut**

```
 <Students>------------------->Both record should be added to one Record
      <Validate>True</Validate>
      <StudentName>Joe</StudentName>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <BookName>C#</BookName>
      <StudentName>Van</StudentName>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <BookName>Java</BookName>
 </Students>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use LINQ to XML.  You parse the XML, get all the child elements in each `Students` element and put them into a a single new `Students` element:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var children = doc.Descendants("Students")
    .Elements();

var newStudents = new XElement("Students", children);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZGDJtH) for a working example.